# Passing batch variables to jobs in Jenkins

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have a job in Jenkins that runs a Windows batch command to retrieve the version number of a DLL:

```
setlocal enableextensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "file=c:\\example.dll"

for /f %%a in (
    'wmic DataFile where "Name='%file%'" get Version ^| find "." '
) do set "currentVersion=%%a"`
```

Looking at the console output, currentVersion does get set properly.

However, after calling this batch command, I try to trigger another job using this variable as a value:

```
Version=%currentVersion%
```

This job doesn't recognize this though, and the literal string `%currentVersion%` gets passed through.

How do I go about passing the value of `currentVersion` from the batch script into the triggered job?

Comment: Where do you use the Version=%currentVersion% reference?

Comment: That's a predefined parameter that I set in the "Trigger/call builds on other projects". Should I pass this through a different way?

Comment: Maybe true a text file.

Comment: @SachaDee Try passing it through as a text file? Like, writing the batch variable to a text file, and passing the path to that through? That seems a bit overkill for something that should be simple.

Comment: Keep in mind that this batch script is simply written into a file and executed in a child process. It does not affect environment of the Jenkins build. Actually, property file approach suggested by @SachaDee is the simplest solution here.

Answer (score 0):

As alluded to in the comments, the variable you set in a batch script won't be visible to other build steps after the batch script execution ends.

You should write the value to a text file, e.g. write `APP_VERSION=1.2.3` to `version.properties` and use the [EnvInject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) to then read in that properties.

Then the environment variable `APP_VERSION` would be available to subsequent build steps, and could be used to trigger another job.